# Extend UserControl.Resources

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I want to provide a simple default style for a `UserControl`, but still be able to extend or override the style when using the control. Below is a sample scenario with a simple `UserControl` and a `Window` containing the control. The intention is for the style for the `Button` provided in the `Window` to override the default style defined in the `UserControl`.

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.TestControl" ... >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Press Me" />
        <Button Content="Touch Me" />
        <Button Content="Tap Me" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Window**

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow" ... >
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl>
            <local:TestControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </Style>
            </local:TestControl.Resources>
        </local:TestControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Problem**

The above code will result in:

- Exception: `Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.`
- InnerException: `Item has already been added.`

The above code is trying to submit two styles with the same key into the same `ResourceDictionary`, so obviously it wasn't going to work. My guess that I am not going to be able to provide a default style for the buttons...

Comment: I know that merged dictionaries can have multiple resources with the same key, and the last one takes precedence. Is there some way that I can use that?

Answer (score 0):

**Insufficient Workaround:** Override default `ResourceDictionary`

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow" ... >
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl>
            <local:TestControl.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </local:TestControl.Resources>
        </local:TestControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

By putting the custom `Button` style in a `ResouceDictionary`, I can override the default one. However, its not just overriding the `Button` style, its overriding all of the resources. So, the `StackPanel` will no longer have a black background. (obviously I could add that to the overriding style as well, but thats not practical on a bigger scale.)